# React - Pass element to component as prop invoking a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have the following function

```
const renderFooter = () => <View />
```

A FlatList component has a prop "ListFooterComponent", which definition is:

```
ListFooterComponent?: React.ComponentType<any> | React.ReactElement<any, string | React.JSXElementConstructor<any>>
```

If I do the following

```
return <FlatList ListFooterComponent={renderEmptyListItem} />
```

But if I do

```
return <FlatList ListFooterComponent={renderEmptyListItem()} />
```

it also works.

Which is the correct way? Whats the difference between both?

Comment: Can you please show me the `renderEmptyListItem` function?

Comment: I also have noticed, that for ListEmptyComponent, if I do not invoke the method, it doesn't work.

Comment: const renderListEmptyComponent = () => <View />    ....     <FlatList ListEmptyComponent={renderListEmptyComponent()} />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one will pass a pointer to your function and let the FlatList trigger it for you.

In the second example, you invoke the function yourself as the component mounts.

The first option is the correct one because you let the component handle it when the user scrolls to the bottom of the list where in the second example it will be immediately invoked.